# How to do if statement for select element in moodle PHP

Tags: php, arrays, forms, moodle

Hey guys so I am currently building a project based on Moodle in PHP and I was just curious how one would be able to remove certain select options within an array for the select option. I was thinking about using the disabledIf function but I can't think of any use cases for it. So for example, here is my code:

```
    $mform->addElement('select', 'showresults', get_string("publish", "choice"), $CHOICE_SHOWRESULTS);

    $mform->addElement('select', 'publish', get_string("privacy", "choice"), $CHOICE_PUBLISH);

    //$mform->disabledIf('publish', 'showresults', 'eq', 0);
```

`$CHOICE_SHOWRESULTS` and `$CHOICE_PUBLISH` are both arrays.

Let's say for instance the choices for the `$CHOICE_SHOWRESULTS` is "I like to party" and "I don't like to party"

If I were to pick "I like to party" then I would get only a subset of `$CHOICE_PUBLISH`

But if I pick "I don't like to party" then I get all of the elements in `$CHOICE_PUBLISH`

In the moodle documentation here https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Form_API

I only see the disableIf that actually works like an if statement but it doesn't really state if a certain element within an array is picked then show some of the results.

So thus I want something like this in code:

```
    $mform->addElement('select', 'showresults', get_string("publish", "choice"), $CHOICE_SHOWRESULTS);
    if ( one choice within $CHOICE_SHOWRESULTS)
          $mform->addElement('select', 'publish', get_string("privacy", "choice"), SUBSET OF $CHOICE_PUBLISH);
    else { //another choice of CHOICE_SHOWRESULTS
          $mform->addElement('select', 'publish', get_string("privacy", "choice"), $CHOICE_PUBLISH);
    }
```

I'm a beginner to Moodle so anything will help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there are no mechanisms for this in mform currently, so basically there are only two choices:

1. Write the js\amd module, that will track the dropdown "change" event, check on the selected choice and adjust second dropdown choices accordingly
2. Do the same scenario but with ajax involved: the event tracker will send ajax request and receive response from server with the "publish" dropdown options.

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to use the 'hierselect' form element which allows you to display 2 select menus, where the selection in the first menu dynamically changes the options in the second menu. I asked a question about it on the Moodle forums ([here](https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=322348)) which shows an example usage.